# Can TensorFlow lite can be build with custom CPU?

Tags: tensorflow, gradle, bazel, aar, tensorflow-lite

I'm looking the TF Lite Android App

Which can be found on GIT: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/java/demo

How can I compile the tensorflow lite framework to use the optimized "atom" cpu type?

Is it possible to compile it on a MAC os with the CPU optimizations for the "atom" cpu?

I want to run the app on an Android device (SDK 22) with an "Intel Atom" Processor.
When I run the application without any changes through Android Studio the rate was about **1200ms per frame**.
Compering the same APK installed on my Galaxy S9 (arm - snapdragon processor) was about **30ms per frame**.

In the "build.gradle" there is this section:

```
dependencies {
...    
compile 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly'

...
}
```

So it's seems that it's downloading the framework,

How can I compile it locally with the CPU optimization and set the app to use it instead of downloading the non optimized nightly version?

I tried to run this tutorial : 
[Installing TensorFlow from Sources](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources) with the cpu flags but not sure exactly how it's helping me with the Android scenario..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your Atom device is x86, use the `--fat_apk_cpu` flag to specify the `x86` ABI:

```
$ bazel build -c opt --cxxopt='--std=c++11' \ 
    --fat_apk_cpu=x86 \
    //tensorflow/contrib/lite/java/demo/app/src/main:TfLiteCameraDemo
```

Switch `x86` with `x86_64` if you're building for a 64-bit device.

The built APK, available at `bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/lite/java/demo/app/src/main/TfLiteCameraDemo.apk`, will contain the x86 `.so` file:

```
$ zipinfo bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/lite/java/demo/app/src/main/TfLiteCameraDemo.apk | grep lib
-rw----     2.0 fat  1434712 b- defN 80-Jan-01 00:00 lib/x86/libtensorflowlite_jni.so
```

If your device is connected, you can use `bazel mobile-install` instead of `bazel build` to directly install the app:

```
$ bazel mobile-install -c opt --cxxopt='--std=c++11' \ 
  --fat_apk_cpu=x86 \ 
  --start_app \
  //tensorflow/contrib/lite/java/demo/app/src/main:TfLiteCameraDemo
```

Comment: keep getting weird compilation errors when doing so :   "ERROR: No default_toolchain found for cpu 'x86'. Valid cpus are: [
  darwin,
  darwin_x86_64,
  k8,
  ios_x86_64,
  ios_i386,
  ios_armv7,
  ios_arm64,
  watchos_i386,
  watchos_armv7k,
  tvos_x86_64,
  tvos_arm64,
  armeabi-v7a,
]"

How can I add this cpu type to this cpu collection?

Comment: What command are you running? Are you building the `cc_library` directly?

Comment: Well now I'm getting this error while running the first command you give me:    ERROR: /Users/myuser/Workspaces/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/lite/java/demo/app/src/main/BUILD:7:1: no such package '@androidsdk//com.android.support': The repository could not be resolved and referenced by '//tensorflow/contrib/lite/java/demo/app/src/main:TfLiteCameraDemo'
ERROR: /Users/myuser/Workspaces/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/lite/java/demo/app/src/main/BUILD:7:1: no such package '@androidsdk//com.android.support': The repository could not be resolved and referenced by

Comment: Please follow [step 3 of the "Building from Source with Bazel" guide](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/java/demo#building-from-source-with-bazel) to set up the Android SDK and NDK in the WORKSPACE file.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wring but the android setting is not in the WORKSPACE file any more.. it's under /third_party/android/android_configuration.bzl . is this the new configuration file location? i change there all the settings.
the tutorials and guide in the site talking about the WORKSPACE setting but it's changed last month in the GIT repo

Comment: It does look like it has changed but the docs are not updated. The error you're getting is for a missing SDK. You can fix that manually by adding the lines `android_sdk_repository(
    name = "androidsdk",
    path = "/path/to/Android/sdk"
)` and `android_ndk_repository(
    name = "androidndk",
    path = "/path/to/ndk"
)` to the WORKSPACE file.

Comment: Thanks it worked! I'm just tryong to understand the CPU types by the documentation, I found this link in the tensor flow site "https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.3/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html"

Where do I need to use the "-march" or "-mtune" to get the Atom processor optimization running on my android device? Am I missing something?

Comment: Found in this link: "https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources" under: This question refers to a later phase in which you'll use bazel to build the pip package. We recommend accepting the default (-march=native), which will optimize the generated code for your local machine's CPU type. However, if you are building TensorFlow on one CPU type but will run TensorFlow on a different CPU type, then consider specifying a more specific optimization flag as described in the gcc documentation (link above).

Comment: I believe you can pass the compiler flags using `--cxxopt`, e.g. `--cxxopt=-march=native`

Comment: Does those flags affect the compilation time\ behavioural on my pc (Mac) or affect the binaries APK (run time) while running on my android device?

Comment: I’m not familiar with this area of compilation, sorry.